# Blender 3.1.0 Repeatedly Rendering Previously Rendered Image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, image

I am trying to render a scene in cycles. I have updated the scene a couple of times already. However, when I try to render an image, it displays the old scene.

I even tried changing the render to EEVEE. But, the issue still persists.

How can I fix it?

Comment: have you add an image into the Video Sequencer? In that case in the Output panel > Post Processing, disable Sequencer

Comment: No. I have not used the video sequencer at all. I have already disabled sequencer but even that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: maybe you have selected a wrong camera, or keyframed it?

Comment: I just modeled the object, added the materials and lighting. I even deleted the camera and added back and there was no keyframes on the timeline. I just uninstalled the latest version and installed the LTS version to check if there was a bug in the newer one.

Comment: in the Scene panel make sure that you've selected the good camera, if it's still not the problem please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I did that. Even installing the LTS version did not fix the issue. Ok I will send the file to you.

Comment: This is the link: [link](https://pasteall.org/blend/7759688e616c4c27ab4b0c85819ff6fc)

Comment: it seems to work: https://zupimages.net/up/22/16/uf54.jpg ... there's a plane but it's just that you haven't disabled it for render in the Outliner

Comment: thank you so much! It was a huge help. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an object called *Plane* that is disabled for preview but still enabled for render, disable it as well:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. You have fixed my issue. Thank you!